# class doesn't get compiled by babel (nextjs / webpack)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, next.js

Problem:

My site uses next js. On 2 pages I get `script1002: syntax error` in IE because of a `class i{constructor(e)...`.

What I tried:

- implementing a polyfill like [in this example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-polyfills)
- The pages with the error both used axios but the error persists when I switched to fetch
- adding this to `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "preset-env": {
          "targets": {
            "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "IE >= 11"]
          },
          "useBuiltIns": "entry"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "lodash",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes"
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here... I don't know 100% if my polyfills are working but babel should transpile classes by default as far as I know. I also couldn't find the source of that `class` in my code yet and am not to sure how to find what package it belongs to.

Comment: Is it because it's not compiling something you have in `node_modules`? I had this problem in my code recently -- many setups will not compile code imported from node_modules by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding

```
 config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
        }
      }
    });
```

into my `next.config.js` fixed it by forcing it to also transpile all `node_modules`